# What are the various ways to say "." (period/dot/full stop)?

Tags: произношение, пунктуация

Examples:
- version 1.5
- period at the end of a sentence
- decimal point
- stackoverflow.com

Comment: Prostokvashino always relevant. [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=MaRW_2tXJr0&t=2528)

Answer (score 11):

In most cases you either say "точка", or nothing. In Russian, there are no different words for "dot", "period" (in sense of punctuation) or "full stop".

## version 1.5

- версия один-пять
- версия один-точка-пять.

## period at the end of a sentence

- точка (e.g. "Ты забыл поставить точку." - "You forgot to put a period/full stop".)

## decimal point

In Russian schools, as in most of Europe, the comma is used to delimit the fractional part, thus it's literally "запятая". However, when reading numbers aloud, you're supposed to convert the notation to decimal fractions and read it like that:

- 20,3  -> двадцать целых, три десятых = twenty wholes (=whole parts), three tenths (=one-tenth parts)
- 345,567 -> триста сорок пять целых, пятьсот шестьдесят семь тысячных = 345 wholes, 567 thousandths

In casual speech, most people don't bother, and use one of the following:

- двадцать и три
- двадцать запятая три
- двадцать точка три (this is common among programmers who are used to the US notation)

If the fractional part is .5, you can use "с половиной" ("and one half") in casual speech:

- 10.5 - десять и пять; десять с половиной

Sometimes you can even omit the word for comma/period if it's clear from the context:

- ноль-пять (0,5) - commonly used to refer to a 0.5L liquor bottle, e.g. "В магазине не забудь взять ноль-пять!" (Don't forget to buy a bottle of vodka!)

## www.stackoverflow.com

- три дубль-вэ (точка) стэковерфлоу (точка) ком
- вэ вэ вэ (точка) стэковерфлоу (точка) ком

I.e. you don't have to read out the period if it's obvious.

Comment: An exception for decimal point as comma is "floating point". Although formally it should be `с плавающей запятой`, people usually don't care and translate `с плавающей точкой`. See for example yandex results.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases *точка* is used, except for decimal delimiter:

- `Версия один точка пять` (or just *один пять*);
- точка в конце предложения;
- десятичная **запятая**;
- `стэковерфлоу точка ком` (but usually just `стэковерфлоу ком`).

In Russian the delimiter between whole numbers and decimals after the "decimal point" is decimal comma. So, the correct way to call this delimiter is:

- десятичная запятая (decimal point)
- числа с плавающей запятой (floating-point numbers)
- пять знаков после запятой (five decimal places)

However, nowadays most books on computer science is published in English and many people translate "decimal point" as "десятичная точка", which is incorrect.

In telegraphy the word точка is used for both 'dot' and 'stop' as well.
For example, Morse code for letter R is `• — •` and it is pronounced as dot-dash-dot. In Russian it is pronounced as `точка-тире-точка`.

In telegram 'STOP' is translated as 'ТЧК':

> SHIP ORANGES BARRELS STOP BROTHERS KARAMAZOV STOP

is translated to Russian as:

> ГРУЗИТЕ АПЕЛЬСИНЫ БОЧКАХ ТЧК БРАТЬЯ КАРАМАЗОВЫ ТЧК

Comment: In Russian the decimal point is not used, the decimal comma is used instead, "2,3" - две целые [и] три десятых, два и три [десятых].

Comment: @YellowSky Yes I know, I just continued to write the answer. My professor of Computer Science has told us about this distinction many times.

Comment: Ah, sorry, first I saw only the beginning of your answer.